# Botman Studio don't reply

Tags: php, laravel, facebook, botman

I started a new project with Botman Studio

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist botman/studio test
```

then I do update

```
cd test
composer up
```

and then installed drivers : facebook and telegram .

```
composer require botman/driver-facebook
composer require botman/driver-telegram
```

done with installing

then I do

```
php artisan key:gen
php artisan serve
```

I go to localhost , it works fine.
I say "hi" it replay "Hello!"

I edit `.env` file added token Facebook and Telegram

```
FACEBOOK_TOKEN=my_app_token
FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET=my_secret
FACEBOOK_VERIFICATION=my_verification
TELEGRAM_TOKEN='my_bo_ttoken'
```

I upload this project to my host

move `public` file to `public_html`
edit `index` file

```
require __DIR__.'/test/vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/test/bootstrap/app.php';
```

the host works fine.
I tested it Responded to all on web and telegram for every user .
But in Facebook it Respond only to me like telegram and web `my_domain/botman/tinker` . when new user say "hi" ,
it not respond at all .

Comment: Did you get your Facebook app reviewed, and set it to live mode already (or any of the new equivalents, for business apps)?

Comment: No , it's new Facebook app. how to set it to live mode @CBroe

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/submission-process

Comment: Thank you, you saved me. @CBroe